# How do I programmatically retrieve the connection strings for a Azure Service Bus Notification Hub?

Tags: azureservicebus

I have a Service Bus for Notification Hub. On that service bus are multiple notification hubs. Each has a pair of connection strings, one for manage,listen,send and one for listen. How can I retrieve the connection strings for these notification hubs? I need to do so programmatically rather than through the portal.

Comment: Are the hubs in the same Service Bus namespace? If so, you could use the namespace SAS keys rather than the individual hub keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should show you how to do it. You'll need the connection string for your notification hub namespace to get started...

```
NamespaceManager nsm = NamespaceManager.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString);

var hubs = nsm.GetNotificationHubs();

foreach (NotificationHubDescription hub in hubs)
{
  foreach (SharedAccessAuthorizationRule rule in hub.Authorization)
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Hub Path: {0}, Key Name {1}, Primary Key: {2}", hub.Path, rule.KeyName, rule.PrimaryKey);
  }
}
```

Comment: I got the specific hub description using GetNotificationHub and specified the path and this logic works. Thank you